# If record exists, delete it and insert a new one. Why isn't this working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, t-sql

I didn't think this would be such a difficult task.

A user takes a quiz and then decides, for whatever reason, to retake the quiz.

Our requirement is to delete the results of the quiz this user has already taken before inserting the results into SurveyAnswers table.

The code below intended to delete existing results per questionId (qid) belonging to the user who is attempting to retake the quiz and then insert the current results.

This should be in one operation.

Then if no results currently exists, then insert the results of the current quiz.

The code isn't inserting or deleteing.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SaveAnswer(ByVal qid As Integer, ByVal cid As Integer, ByVal ct As String, ByVal cscore As Integer)
    Dim al As ArrayList = CType(Session("AnswerList"), ArrayList)

    If al Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("List.aspx")
    End If

    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT QuestionId FROM SurveyAnswers WHERE questionId = @qid and UserName = @cuser " & _
                           "BEGIN delete from SurveyAnswers where UserName=@cuser and QuestionId=@qid " & _
                           "insert into surveyanswers(QuestionID,ChoiceID,ChoiceText,Username,dateTaken) values(@qid,@cid,@ct,@cuser,getDate()) END " & _
                           "Else BEGIN insert into surveyanswers(QuestionID,ChoiceID,ChoiceText,Username,dateTaken) values(@qid,@cid,@ct,@cuser,getDate()) END", cnn)
    Dim p1 As New SqlParameter("@qid", qid)
    Dim p2 As New SqlParameter("@cid", IIf(cid = 0, DBNull.Value, cid))
    Dim p3 As New SqlParameter("@ct", IIf(ct = "", DBNull.Value, ct))
    Dim p4 As New SqlParameter("@cuser", Session("UserName"))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p4)
    cnn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: An advice, I would move everything in a stored procedure

Comment: Missing ")" after "EXISTS"?

Comment: Have you successfully run this query in SQL Server Management Studio? If not, then do so before trying to get it in your code.

Comment: Why do you need the `EXISTS` check anyway? Just run the `DELETE` statement. If no rows match nothing will be deleted and it just searches for the match once.

Comment: Gurus, thank you, all of you for your inputs.

@KarlAnderson, yes, I have run the query and it seems to work. For instance, after making the correction recommended by Bartoszky(thanks), I am able to insert records now. However, duplicates are still being inserted. In other words, existing record is not beind deleted before another one of the same questionId is being inserted.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I tried your own suggestion by removing the EXISTS and it is still not deleting existing record before inserting it again.

For instance, let's say we have a questionID of 20, when we attempt to insert record containing that questionId again, the existing one needs to be deleted first. This is not happening.

Comment: Since the `INSERT`s are identical you can simply have an `IF` for the `DELETE` and always execute the `INSERT` (rather than using an `ELSE`).

Comment: @HABO, maybe I am not thinking correctly here but is this what you mean?

If exists(select from table where...)
begin delete from table where...
insert into table (fields) values(...)END

Is this what you mean? How does that solve the problem. I humbly ask for example if you don't mind.

Thanks

Comment: If the delete is not working then break it down. Start with "delete from SurveyAnswers where UserName=@cuser and QuestionId=@qidp"

Comment: `if exists ( select 42 from SurveyAnswers where ... ) begin delete SurveyAnswers where ... end; insert into SurveyAnswers ...` Aside: Note that what you are doing is not atomic unless it is contained within a transaction at an appropriate isolation level. While a single user is unlikely to be answering the same survey question more than once at the same time, you should be aware of the issue and make an explicit decision to handle or ignore it. I concur with implementing it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @HABO, can you please put this on asnwer context so I can give you create. I had to make some minor changes to my asp.net code to get everything working.

Thanks for the help. Thanks to everyone who contributed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a comment promoted to an answer at the request of the OP:

```
if exists ( select 42 from SurveyAnswers where ... )
  begin
  delete SurveyAnswers where ...
  end;
insert into SurveyAnswers ...
```

Aside: Note that what you are doing is not atomic unless it is contained within a transaction at an appropriate isolation level. While a single user is unlikely to be answering the same survey question more than once at the same time, you should be aware of the issue and make an explicit decision to handle or ignore it. I concur with implementing it in a stored procedure, e.g.:

```
create procedure dbo.InsertSurveyAnswer
  -- NB: The prior answer, if any, is deleted.
  @QuestionId as Int,
  @ChoiceId as Int,
  @ChoiceText as NVarChar(64),
  @Username as NVarChar(64)
  as

  set nocount on;

  set transaction isolation level serializable;
  begin transaction;

  -- Attempt to delete any prior answer for this user/question.
  delete from SurveyAnwers
    where Username = @Username and QuestionId = @QuestionId;

  -- Save the new answer.
  insert into SurveyAnswers
    ( QuestionId, ChoiceId, ChoiceText, Username, DateTaken ) values
    ( @QuestionId, @ChoiceId, @ChoiceText, @Username, GetDate() );

  commit transaction;
```

As suggested by Martin Smith, you may was well simply execute the `delete` instead of wasting the resources to determine if it is needed. You could check the value of `@@RowCount` after the `delete` if you had some reason to know whether or not a row was deleted.